# How to make a death counter in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, so I am making a pvp arena. I want to be able to track the number of deaths each person has. So if they hit 5 they are teleported to a "waiting cell" until the next round.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this: do the first one first then the next one

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay list Deaths
```

This will display the player's amount of deaths when you push the Tab button.

Comment: Could you properly format the code/commands by indenting it by 4 spaces?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms I've edited my post to meet your request.

Comment: If you want the scores to show on the right side in a sidebar instead of when holding tab, use `sidebar` instead like this: `/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Deaths`