# How to add a deathcount to the new scoreboards in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

So I have a MCPE realm and  would like to add a deathcount as a scoreboard so we can see who dies the most.

Problem is I tried doing the steps for java edition [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169737/how-to-make-a-death-counter-in-minecraft) but that didn't work (it came back with a syntax error.

I would like to know how to achieve the same effect in minecraft PE.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this with two command blocks and a comparator. First, put a command block down where they would spawn that says:

`testfor @p[x=`**(x-coord)**`,y=`**(y-coord)**`,z=`**(z-coord)**`,r=1]` and make it repeating and always active.
Where,
**(x-coord)** = x coordinate of where they spawn
**(y-coord)** = y coordinate of where they spawn
**(z-coord)** = z coordinate of where they spawn

This will detect when they spawn. Next, put a comparator from the `testfor` command block into the second block that says:
`execute @p`**(put the coordinates of the where they spawn here)** `scoreboard players add @p 1`

Now, whenever they step on top of the command block it will add one score to Death, or whatever you want the objective to be named. Just be careful if the circuit is within render distance of the spawn. I suggest a few blocks underneath the spawn. This system should work, as long as they spawn on the coordinates.

Comment: Just remember to add the objective first.

Comment: I made some minor changes to formatting to help make the answer a bit easier to read, feel free to tweak it if you think something was changed that shouldn't be. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks, it looks a lot better. I can solving problems but not explain how to solve them.

Comment: No problem, and nice answer! That is the great thing about Arqade, there are lots of other people that can help clean-up and clarify answers if they have a good base to work off of. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatley I was hoping to use a deathcount on a survival server where players can use beds. I suppose I could constantly set `/spawnpoint @a` to the world spawn. But anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: sorry that it doesn't work for you, when they update that feature, i will let u know.

Answer (score 0):

The scoreboard command used in the java edition does not work on the pocket edition, so you can not make a deathcount that way. You might be able to find a mod online to be able to have a deathcount on pocket edition, but vanilla minecraft pocket edition does not have that capability.

source: https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/scoreboard_command.php

Comment: Actually they just added it in the newest update
https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Bedrock_Edition_1.7

Comment: Oh I see, nevermind then.

Comment: can you undo the -1 please :)

Comment: There you go :P

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that my commands before will add a score when the first spawn. Fixing this is complicated.

First, add a new scoreboard objective called Spawn.

Second, you need to add to the testfor command block. 
*testfor @p[x=**(x-coord)**,y=**(y-coord)**,z=**(z-coord)**,r=1]* needs to become *testfor @p[x=**(x-coord)**,y=**(y-coord)**,z=**(z-coord)**,r=1,scores={Spawn=1}]* This will make it so that until the score *Spawn* becomes 1, the player doesn't get any death scores.

For the next part, I suggest making a spawn room with a button being the only way out. behind the button, there should be two command blocks connected via redstone, set up in the fashion below[image] one with the command: *scoreboard players set @p[x=**(x-coord)**,y=**(y-coord)**,z=**(z-coord)**,r=1] Spawn 1* .

The second command block should be a simple teleport block that teleports them out of the spawn room. This is the simplest fix I could come up with for this specific scenario. If someone else has an easier way, please comment it.